# Erro Too many connections Hibernate+MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho uma aplicação em desenvolvimento em Java utilizando Hibernate e PrimeFaces, na tela de listagem de itens tenho a opção de fazer uma pesquisa por algumas informações em tempo real utilizando vários filtros.

Porém ao executar a aplicação e realizar alguns teste tenho seguinte retorno na saída do meu console de desenvolvimento.

```
WARN:   SQL Error: 1040, SQLState: 08004
ERROR:   Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too   many connections"
Informações:   javax.el.ELException: /listaProduto.xhtml @45,83 value="#{produtoBean.pesquisa()}": org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
javax.el.ELException: /listaProduto.xhtml @45,83 value="#{produtoBean.pesquisa()}": org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:1002)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:629)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:436)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:428)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:717)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
...
```

É possível eu limpar as pesquisas conforme for realizando novas?

Comment: Vamos precisar de mais detalhes: como está seu código para abrir/fechar sessão do Hibernate? Ou ela é gerenciada por algum framework (Spring, EJB, etc)? Este erro ocorre sempre ou é intermitente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi verificado a forma com que faço a comunicação e obtenção dos dados via `Hibernate` no código, ao certificar de que estava ficando aberta threads que não tinham mais utilidade e elas estavam consumindo memória do computador. Foi alterado o código fazendo com que eu não abrisse uma thread e a deixasse aberta.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite Paulo,

Faz um teste, altera o arquivo my.cnf dentro de /etc/mysql/, e modifica os seguintes parâmetros:
max_user_connections=0
max_connections=1000

Caso você não possua acesso ao servidor, ou esteja utilizando uma instancia compartilhada, será necessário você entrar em contato com a prestadora.

Se ainda assim persistir o problema e seu caso não se encaixe no item acima, verifique se está utilizando corretamente a gestão de conexões.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/